# IntelliJ IvyIDEA adding unwanted module dependencies

Tags: intellij-idea, ivy

I have been having trouble removing module dependencies from IntelliJ and instead using Ivy dependencies.

I have Module A which is dependent on module B and both are in my project, I have edited Module B and want to keep it in my project but also want Module A to depend on the Ivy repository version of Module B - not the one in my workspace.

I go to the Project Structure window and remove Module B as a dependency of Module A and press OK and use IvyIDEA to resolve dependencies, if I then open Project Structure I find that intelliJ has undone my changes and re-added my Module B as a dependency instead of using Ivy.

How do I stop it doing this?

Comment: Some code examples would help with understanding the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how code samples would help.  I'll post a rephrasing of the OP's question in a sec.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is a known issue with the IvyIDEA plugin. Here's a [link to the issue](https://code.google.com/p/ivyidea/issues/detail?id=36) on the old google code ivyidea repo. There are some suggestions for workarounds as well:

Comment: The issue that the OP (and I) are having is that IvyIDEA seems to be adding *module* dependencies based on *intuited* connections within your code, rather than *explicit* jar dependencies specified in ivy.xml.

To create an example out of his issue, he has a java class in in ModuleA (called ModuleA.java).  This references a class in ModuleB (called ModuleB.java).  This class is also included in module-b.jar, which is specified in ivy.xml in ModuleA.

Comment: But when you resolve, IvyIDEA auto-adds ModuleB as a *module* dependency, and it does not pull in module-b.jar. First of all, I'm unclear on why IvyIDEA would ever add modules rather than jars from ivy.xml.  Secondly, it is not including the explicitly referenced module-b.jar unless I remove ModuleB from my project, in which case it resolves just fine.